# Is it possible to find a match on last occurence between two words with regex?

Tags: regex, prtg

I have a text log file that look like this:

```
    --Start 10:00:00
    --Success
    --End 10:01:02

    --Start 10:02:32
    --Success
    --End 10:02:40
    
    --Start 10:02:00
    --Error
    --End 10:02:05
```

The last block is the last registered event.
Is there a way to match a regex ONLY when in the last block "error" shows up?

I tried something like `((?=Start)(*.)(?=Error)(*.)(?=End))(?:.(?!\\))` but does not work. I am not a regex expert.

I am trying to use it on PRTG to monitoring a service.

Really appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: You may try: `[\s\S]*(--Start.*\s+--Error\s+--End.*)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading this page https://www.paessler.com/manuals/prtg/regular_expressions the supported regex engine is PCRE.

You could match the block that contains Error while asserting that at the end, there is no part following that starts with `--Start`

```php
^\h*--Start .*\R\h*--Error\R\h*--End\b.*$(?!\R\s*--Start\b)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\h*--Start .*\R` Match the line with start followed by a newline
- `\h*--Error\R` Match the line with Error followed by a newline
- `\h*--End\b.*$` Match the line with End until the end of the string
- `(?!\R\s*--Start\b)` Negative lookahead, match a newline and assert that  there is not a first line following that starts with `--Start`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gb6X5x/1)

Comment: It did not work cause PRTG does not support regex flags as reported on the manual page you have linked. "_italic_PRTG supports regular expression (regex) options in the form (?isgmxUJ) and their negations like, for example, (?-i). PRTG does not support regex flags like, for example, /g (global), /s (single line), or /gs, and does not correctly search for the target string if you try to set flags." Your answer still very helpful anyway:)

Comment: @MMDevAdvantix You could try `(?m)` the inline multiline option `(?m)^\h*--Start .*\R\h*--Error\R\h*--End\b.*$(?!\R\s*--Start\b)` https://regex101.com/r/bgjwXv/1

Comment: @MMDevAdvantix Another option could be `[\s\S]*(--Start.*\s+--Error\s+--End.*)(?![\s\S]*--Start)` https://regex101.com/r/ZhhzOz/1

Comment: both options do not work, I also tried to simplify the regex, I marked your answer as valid because it is useful anyway and the problem seems to be related to the limitations of PRTG. I will contact their support! Thanks so much for your valuable help :)